# How can I redefine a key that is currently used as the start of a key sequence?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, prefix-keys

I want to redefine `C-w` to run one of my commands. `evil` has already defined a number of key sequences that start with `C-w` to run its commands. So my command does not run, Emacs just waits for me to complete the sequence.

Is there a way I can undefine all existing sequences starting with `C-w` so that Emacs will then run my `C-w` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `evil` binds `C-w` to the `evil-window-map`,
within which it stores the rest of the keybindings.

In looking at the source code, the core spot it happens is in
`evil-motion-state-map`.  Depending on how you set
`evil-want-C-w-delete` and `evil-want-C-w-in-emacs-state`, it
will also bind the key in `evil-insert-state-map` and
`evil-emacs-state-map` as well.

You can undefine the key with:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "\C-w" nil)
```

and, if necessary, with:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map "\C-w" nil)
(define-key evil-emacs-state-map  "\C-w" nil)
```

You can now bind a different key combination to `evil-windows-map`.
Here's an uncomfortable example, but you get the point:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "\C-!" 'evil-windows-map)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. So it seems Evil does funky things with key bindings that need to be handled via Evil. I will bear that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If your `C-w` command is shadowed by evil-mode, the following undefine evil's `C-w` command.

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-w") nil)
```

If you want to use `C-w` command even on insert-state of evil-mode, you should evaluate the following.

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-w") nil)
```

Comment: Please explain how this post is not a duplicate of the other answer.

Comment: Sorry, while I wrote this answer, you posted your answer. I didn't imitate your answer. Your answer is more detailed, so I will also refer to your answer.